# No puedo mostrar el bucle correctamente

Tags: java, bucle-for

**podrían ayudarme a completar la secuencia del los múltiplos?**

```
 int dim=5;
int con = 5;
//Recorrer filas
for(int fila=0;fila<dim;fila++){  
 //Recorrer valores de la fila       
 for(int val=0;val<=fila;val++){

  if(val == 0){
     
 System.out.print(cont*10);         
   }
                        
}
con--;
System.out.println();       
}

*No entiendo cómo hacer que 
 se muestren los valores 
 multiplos*
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el problema con el código que nos compartes? Qué error tiene? Edita tu pregunta y cuéntanos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prácticamente lo tienes ya solo te falta que el el segundo bucle for te vaya añadiendo los valores múltiplos que se podría a; adir en ese mismo print.
Basicamente el print le he anadido que vaya restando el numero correspondiente de la linea tantas veces como valores tenga la linea empezando en 0. (y un espacio en blaco para que quede todo separado)

```
    int dim =5;
    int con = 5; 
    for(int fila=0;fila<dim;fila++){  
        for(int val=0;val<=fila;val++){ 
            System.out.print(((con*10)-(val*con))+" ");      
        }
        con--;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Eres un crack, mira que lo tenía ya pero no me funcionaba

Comment: Sólo cambiaría la forma que muestres por pantalla: ``System.out.print((con*(10-val))+"\t");``  para mostrar más ordenado